# Global function not visible inside function

Tags: javascript, angular, google-analytics

I am injecting google analytics code via a file named `analytics.js` inside webpage header like this:

```
<script src="/assets/js/analytics.js"></script>
```

This works fine. If I go to webpage, I have access to global function `ga` from my console.

However, in my service, which looks like that:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Router, NavigationEnd} from "@angular/router";
var ga:any;

@Injectable()
export class GoogleAnalyticsService{
    constructor(){
      console.log(ga);
    }

    test(){
        console.log(typeof ga);
    }
}
```

In both cases, console output is undefined. I inject my Angular2 at the bottom of html code, so it is loaded as last script.

What is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace:

```
var ga:any;
```

with

```
declare var ga: any;
```

First one creates new variable while last one declares type